# Holomorphic function $f$ on ball around $0$: $f$ is in $\Bbb R$ on the real axis and complex everywhere else, then $f$ takes at most one zero.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be a holomorphic on a disk around the origin with radius $r$ and takes real values on the real axis and non real values on the rest of the disk.
Show $f$ has at most one zero.

Comment: Presumably you mean "at most one zero in the disk".  Hint: if there is more than one, $f'$ has a zero at some real point in the disk.  Show $f$ is real at some on-real point near there...

Comment: My idea was to use the argument principle and a circular path with radius r-1/n. Using that it can only intersect twice the real axis and extending the limit to r should give me the result?